# Using state to switch SF symbol icons

Tags: swiftui

If a user taps on a photo it switches to a drawing with the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView : View {

    @State var photo = true
    var imagePhoto = "Day-1"
    var imageVector = "Dag-1"

        var body: some View {

            Image(photo ? imagePhoto : imageVector)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: 200)
                .background(Color.black)
                .padding(.leading, 0)
                .tapAction {
                    self.photo.toggle()
            }

        }
    }
```

What if I want to do the same with changing icons from SF symbols? The following code doesn't work.

```
Image(photo ? systemName: "photo" : systemName: "pencil.circle")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using it wrong, this is the right syntax:

```swift
Image(systemName: photo ?  "photo" : "pencil.circle")
```